# Python: Exception handling in generators code

Tags: python

I have following code which reads user's uploaded file and displays it on the preview page, the expected input file is plain text but some user complains that they are getting following errors,

> data = fileObj.read(4194304)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/codecs.py",
>   line 698, in read
>       return self.reader.read(size)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/codecs.py",
>   line 501, in read
>       newchars, decodedbytes = self.decode(data, self.errors) UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa9 in position
>   15: invalid start byte

Python code to read the file:

```
def gen():
    with codecs.open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as fileObj:
        while True:
            # 4MB chunk (4 * 1024 * 1024 Bytes)
            data = fileObj.read(4194304)
            if not data:
                break
            yield data

return Response(gen(), mimetype='text/plain')
```

How do I write error handler for generator which will switch the encoding to `latin-1` and try to read the file again instead of throwing exception?

**Update sample file data which tend to fail:**

```
/*
    Copyright � 2017, J. Wayne Schneider - All Rights Reserved
    Unauthorized copying of this file, via any medium is strictly prohibited
    Proprietary and confidential
    Written by J. Wayne Schneider <jwaynes@gmail.com>, May 2017
*/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be my take on it.

```
def main():

    def gen(method):
        with open('path', encoding=method) as fileObj:
            while True:
                data = fileObj.read(4194304)
                if not data:
                    break
                yield data

    try:
        rr = [*gen('utf-8')]
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        rr = [*(gen('latin-1')]
    return Response(rr, mimetype='text/plain')
```

---

```
def main():

    def gen():
        try:
            with open('path', encoding='utf-8') as fileObj:
                while True:
                    data = fileObj.read(4194304)
                    if not data:
                        break
                    yield data
        except (UnicodeDecodeError, UnicodeEncodeError, UnicodeError):
            with open('path', encoding='latin-1') as fileObj:
                while True:
                    data = fileObj.read(4194304)
                    if not data:
                        break
                    yield data

    return Response(gen('utf-8'), mimetype='text/plain')
```

This is the version with try; except build in to the gen, less likely to throw any errors.

Comment: It is not working, In response Python sends an exception details.

Comment: What is the exception though?

Comment: data = fileObj.read(4194304)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/codecs.py", line 698, in read
    return self.reader.read(size)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/codecs.py", line 501, in read
    newchars, decodedbytes = self.decode(data, self.errors)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa9 in position 15: invalid start byte

Comment: Did you try the second version in the answer?

Comment: Don't you think it will break the DRY rule?

I had that in my mind but was looking for better solution :)

Comment: You are completely right, I changed one last thing in the first one; that should definitely work; if not I'm speechless.

Comment: No it's not working either :( Same as earlier response send and response contains Exception details as earlier.

Comment: I think I got one more idea, changed the first part of the answer once again. Since the error occurs when the generator actually starts getting the info from the file, the error should occur as soon as you cast the generator into a list hence this time it can catch the exception. Although I have no idea if your first argument for `Render` can be a list or not; if it can be, I think I got it this time. :^) Or you can simply return a list in the function; basically the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

An example of using try, except to handle errors:

```
def gen():
    with codecs.open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as fileObj:
        while True:
            # 4MB chunk (4 * 1024 * 1024 Bytes)
            try:
                data = fileObj.read(4194304)
                if not data:
                    break
                yield data
            except UnicodeDecodeError:
                #do whatever you want on fail here
            except:
                raise ValueError('object could not be read, even after we caught the unicode error and did something else.')

    return Response(gen(), mimetype='text/plain')
```

Comment: I do not want to omit the data instead I want to switch the encoding to `latin-1` and try to read the file again.

Comment: It was by mistake, I was replying to Işık Kaplan

Comment: What's the purpose of `if not data: break` in the `try` statement? Does it break out of `gen` altogether? (why not just add another `except` branch?)